# delete node from ul element using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="tagsul">
              <li class="tagsLi"><div class="tagsSpan">test<img class="removeitem" src="../Images/Cross.png" onclick="UpdateTag(0, 2)"></div>,</li>
              </li>
          </ul>
```

the function that is being called is as below

```
function UpdateTag(data, index) {

    var $this = $(this);
    alert($this);
    $(this).parents('.tagsLi').remove();
    index--;
    //.remove('li:eq(' + index + ')');
}
```

i tried many permutation combination but still i m not able to delete the li node from which the function is called. please help.

Comment: Have you tried passing this into the function from the onclick declaration e.g. onclick="UpdateTag(this)". I think that would give you the calling element.

Comment: Inside the function, `this` refers to `window` not to the clicked element. I recommend to use jQuery to bind the event handler and then it will probably work. Read some documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Comment: yes passing this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `this` to your onclick like: `onclick="UpdateTag(0, 2, this)"`

Then you can use your function like:

```
 function UpdateTag(data, index, e) {
      var el = $(e);
      el.parents('.tagsul').children('.tagsLi').remove()
      index--;
      //.remove('li:eq(' + index + ')');
  }
```

DEMO **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy8Gk/1/)**

Comment: The problem is that `this` does not refer to the correct element/object.

Comment: @user2650513, great. You can click to accept and/or vote up the best answer. That way we receive points for helping you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
   <ul class="tagsul">
          <li class="tagsLi"><div class="tagsSpan">test<img id="img12" class="removeitem" src="../Images/Cross.png" onclick="javascript:return UpdateTag(0, 2,this)"></div>,</li>
          </li>
      </ul>
</body>
</html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function UpdateTag(data, index,imgobj) {

  var img_obj = $(imgobj);

  alert(img_obj.parent('div').attr('class'));

    img_obj.parents('.tagsLi').remove();
   index--;
  //.remove('li:eq(' + index + ')');
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is refers to the window rather than your image element.

Why don't you simply use jquery to detect click and update, works fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var index = $('img').length;
    $('img').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        alert($this);
        $(this).parents('.tagsLi').remove();
        index--;
    });

});
```

## **[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ybPzP/20/)**

Here you can use `$(this)`, as `$(this)` refers to object being clicked.

or, pass this with your function, as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, `$(this)` is confusing. It is not clear what should be "this" element in a function. Also, I would recommend not using inline function calls since it will raise an error whenever JS is disabled. You could handle the click event with jQuery like this:

```
$('.removeitem').click(function(e){
    var $this=$(this);
    //var index=$this.data('index');
    //var data=$this.data('info');
    $this.parents('.tagsLi').remove();
});
```

By changing the img tag to this:

```
<img class="removeitem" data-index="0" data-info="2" src="../Images/Cross.png" />
```

It has the benefit that if JS is disable, the handler won't be attached to the element in the first place, hence preventing a quite predictable error.

See working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j9aLB/1/).